Detect Windows Power Save mode in browser without document.addEventListener("visibilitychange")
I want to make browser alert and make user be logout when A System goes power save mode.
As you see on title, I can't use visibilityChange Attributes on my javascript.
Please someone give me some Hint or whether it's possible or not.
I searched google. But hard to find an answer.
I would be more glad if you provided an example.
Thank you.

Detecting when a device enters energy-save mode is not currently supported; however, we can detect if a site tab has been discarded using document.wasDiscarded. if (document.wasDiscarded) { // The page was reloaded after a discard. } else { // The page was not reloaded after a discard. }

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
